# how to get the percentage for the predicted labels in google cloud vision

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

i have succesfully get the description for each and every label from google vision API ,but i still need to get the percentage predicted for each label , can any one help me

i do this to get description for label

```
filename = photos.save(request.files['photo'])
file_url = photos.url(filename)
response = client.label_detection(image=image)
labels = response.label_annotations
for label in labels:
    print(label.description)
```

the outputs

```
Hair
Forehead
Chin
White-collar worker
Eyebrow
Hairstyle
Cheek
```

> i'd like to get result like this :

```
Hair 80%
Forehead 10%
Chin 50%
White-collar worker 0%
Eyebrow 5%
Hairstyle 1%
Cheek 20%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
for label in labels:
    desc, score = label.description, int(label.score * 100)
    print(f"{desc} {score}%")
```

Comment: thanks a lot this was help me , but i get the result in my view.htm like this 0.9788822531700134 it's to long !

Comment: yes of course brother, i have one more question i passed the labels to view and i do {{ label.description }} {{label.score * 100}} how can i get it like inside the method

Comment: @devpython f-string in python uses, this `f"{variable}"` syntax. You can use it any where in method as a string like given syntax, even as `f"{variable * 100}"`.